# login() and logout() of django.contrib.auth.views

Tags: python, django

//models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    addr1= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    addr2= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state= models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm 
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password'}))
```

//project/urls.py(the outer one)

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from student.forms import LoginForm

url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/home'}),
```

//login.html(the login template)

```
<div class="container">
        <section id="content">
            <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h1>Login Form</h1>

                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <img src="{% static 'student/patient.jpg' %}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">

                </div>

                <div class="username">
                    {{ form.username.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.username }}                 
                </div>

                <div class="password">
                    {{ form.password.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.password }}
                </div>

                <div class="submitb">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="mybtn">

                </div>

                <div class="resetb">
                    <input type="submit" value="Reset">
                    <a href="#forgotpwd">Forgot password?</a>

                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />




            </form>
        </section>




    </div>
```

this is the settings.py
//settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/sample'
```

is the login() and logout() being called here when i login and logout in this manner?...if not then can i extend the login() and logout() of django.contrib.auth???

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can extends of login as well

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'the name of the url'
LOGOUT_URL = 'the name of the url'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
```

`url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
 url(r'^logout/', logout, {'next_page': reverse_lazy('the name of the url')}, name='logout'),`

login.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
<div class="form-group">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="username">Usuario</label>
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required placeholder="Usuario">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required placeholder="Contraseña">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
```

Comment: where have you extended the login() ?

Comment: Import django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout and use these in the urls